# Jquery - hide element after cookie is made

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

i have a hidden element which appears upon users scroll. When a text "Click to close" (located inside the element) is clicked then the element hiddes and sets a cookie, which prevents it's visibility upon refresh. My question: is it possible that the element stays hidden upon setting a `cookie` without refresh? Currently when text inside it is clicked element hides but then it shows up again upon scroll.

My current setup: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0t877knu/).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this solely by testing for the cookie, you should move the cookie check conditional into your scroll event handler. Right now, you're binding the scroll event on page load if the cookie doesn't exist, but once it is set, you're not unbinding the scroll event. See [updated fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/0t877knu/3/)

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    if (document.cookie.indexOf("testCookie") < 0) {
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (y > 300) {
            $("#test").show();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Josh, spot on. I've also combined top distance with cookie testing and it works.

Answer (score 1):

The most-straightforward approach would be to note that the item was hidden:

```
$(".set-cookies").on("click", function () {
    $("#test").hide();
    $("#test").data('hidden', true);
});
```

and respect that when scrolling:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if ((y > 300) && ! $('#test').data('hidden')) {
        $("#test").show();
    }
});
```

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0t877knu/1/).

Comment: Thanks Paul, wish i could give multiple accepted answers - voted up.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would solve it, by unbinding the scroll listener, this improves the performance.

```
function setCookie() {
    days = 15;
    CookieDate = new Date();
    if (days > 0) {
        CookieDate.setTime(CookieDate.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        document.cookie = "testCookie=true; expires=" + CookieDate.toGMTString();
    }
    if (days === 0) {
        document.cookie = "testCookie=true;";
    }
}

function hasCookie() {
    return document.cookie.indexOf("testCookie") > 0;
}

function scrollListener() {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 300) {
        $("#test").show();
    }   
}

$(".set-cookies").on("click", function () {
    setCookie();
    $("#test").hide();

    // remove scroll listener
    $(document).off("scroll", scrollListener);
});


// initial check on startup
if (hasCookie()) {
    // cookie set, hide message
    $("#test").hide();
} else {
    // cookie missing, register scroll listener
    $(document).scroll(scrollListener);
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0t877knu/8/